# SQL and Excel - Performance

Tags: sql, excel, performance

I regularly import data from SQL to Excel and from there pivot the data to report (Financial Reporting). I find the data tables are usually around 50Mb +. Is it better for the speed of the query and the size of the Excel file to insert additional calculations in the Excel table or do the calc in the SQL code?

Comment: It depends on how's the complexity of your calculation.  For long term, I will suggest you to put all calculation in SQL (which is the data layer), and Excel is for the presentation only.

Answer (score 0):

In general you will have a better performance when you do it in SQL but when it takes you 10 hours to implement it in SQL and just 5 Minutes in Excel, you should ask yourself which makes more sense for you (runtime vs. time of implementation, is it worth it?).

You should also consider the power of the underlying machine. The Server with DBMS will probably have more power compared to your local machine.